# Capturing “xxxxxxxxxx”

Tags: c#, .net, regex

This is a pretty simple question but I'm somewhat stumped.

I am capturing sections of text that match "xxxxxxxxxx".   It works fine.

```
string pattern = "(?<quotePair>\"[^/\"]*\")";
```

Now I want to make a new pattern to capture “xxxxxxxxxx”...  I used:

```
string pattern2 = "(?<lrquotePair>“[^/\"“]*”)";
```

For some reason the second pattern won't catch anything.  What am I missing?

Comment: works fine in python, probably a language issue then, what language are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your patterns are more complicated than how you describe them - for example, the first one won't match `"foo/bar"`, and the second one won't match `“foo/bar”` or `“foo"bar”`. Perhaps your input falls into one of those categories?

If there is an encoding problem, it's not with the regex - .NET regexes support Unicode just fine. But it might be that you didn't read the text in the correct encoding in the first place - try printing it out and check that the fancy `“”` quotes are still there. In particular, if you use `StreamReader` class with a single-argument constructor (or `File.OpenText` helper), it defaults to UTF-8 encoding for input, which might not be what you actually have there.

Comment: Thanks Pavel.  Yeah, I meant for them to have those particular details in them.  That isn't the problem.  I can take the same piece of text, and merely switch " to “ and " to ”, and suddenly it won't match.

Comment: I'm pretty tired.  Seem to have missed the second paragraph.  I think this may be my problem.  I am using HtmlAgilityPack to output to a StringWriter.  Now I understand why it is turning those characters into gobbledy-gook when it prints out.

Comment: The web pages I am working with are charset="ISO-8859-1", StringWriter's encoding is UnicodeEncoding.  I am reading the files into HtmlAgilityPack, then outputting them to a StringWriter.  

Could this be the problem?  How might I rectify it?

Comment: When I check the HtmlAgilityPack for the encoding it gives me: SBCSCodePageEncoding

Comment: Anyone out there no how I can get around this?

Comment: "SBCS" is simply "single-byte character set". It looks like it's a generic class covering all encodings that are based on Windows codepages. What does it give you if you query the encoding's CodePage property?

Comment: 1252 is the CodePage property value

Comment: oops I had it messed up.  The real encoding was Latin1, CodePage: 28591

Answer (score 1):

[Encoding might be getting in your way.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) Try with `\u0093` and `\u0094` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected something like this.  Let me look at the link.

Comment: I just tried it with 
string pattern2 = "(?<lrquotePair>\u0093[^/\"“]*\u0094)";

It didn't seem to work, but hopefully I'm just tired...  Is that regex correct by your eyes?

Comment: try using "(?<lrquotePair>\u201c[^/\"\u201c\u201d]*\u201d)" as that’s what http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs#Quotation_marks_in_electronic_documents says the code points are

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your second regex. Are you sure the input string is correct? The characters you're trying to match are not plain ASCII, so maybe there's a problem with a character encoding mismatch.